# NS_ENUM in Swift class as a property

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I've created an Objective-C enum in `EnumsHeader.h` file and imported that into `<Module>-Bridging-Header.h` `#import "EnumsHeader.h"`. I'm able to create a property of this enum type in a Swift class (`ClassA.Swift`). When I refer to this property from `ClassB.m` (Objective-C) class, I'm seeing compilation error: **Property 'optionsFromA' not found on object of type 'ClassA *'**

Am I missing anything here ?

**EnumsHeader.h**

```
#ifndef EnumsHeader_h
#define EnumsHeader_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, EnumOption) {
    EnumOptionA,
    EnumOptionB,
    EnumOptionC
};

#endif
```

**ClassA.swift**

```
public class ClassA: NSObject {
    public var optionsFromA: EnumOption!
}
```

**ClassB.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestEnumsInterop-Swift.h"

@class ClassB;

@interface ClassB:NSObject

@end

@implementation ClassB

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        ClassA *a = [ClassA new];
        a.optionsFromA = EnumOptionA; //<--- Property 'optionsFromA' not found on object of type 'ClassA *'

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C has no Optional Value,
You can declare the optionsFromA as:

```
public class ClassA: NSObject {
    public var optionsFromA: EnumOption = .A
}
```